# missing information in tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

Taking the 'mtcars' data and moving it into a tibble

```
data<- tibble(mtcars)
```

Noted that the first column which was the vehicle make has now become in the tibble just a numeric list 1,2,3 etc

Fairly new to R so is there a way to tell a tibble to keep the format of the original data?

Answer (score 1):

`tibble`s don't support rownames, to maintain the rownames you can create a new column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mtcars %>% rownames_to_column('make') %>% tibble()

#   make      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Mazda …  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2 Mazda …  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3 Datsun…  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
# 4 Hornet…  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
# 5 Hornet…  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
# 6 Valiant  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
# 7 Duster…  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
# 8 Merc 2…  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
# 9 Merc 2…  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#10 Merc 2…  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as `tibble` doesn't keep the row names, you can use `dplyr::as_tibble` which as an option to create a column with row names:

```
as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = "names_car")
```

Output:

```
 names_car               mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Mazda RX4          21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2 Mazda RX4 Wag      21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3 Datsun 710         22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4 Hornet 4 Drive     21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5 Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6 Valiant            18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7 Duster 360         14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8 Merc 240D          24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9 Merc 230           22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10 Merc 280           19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
```